# Sitecore 10.0.1 Unversioned Images not rendering across languages

Tags: media-library

I created an image in Media library using Sitecore Unversioned Media Template.
After addign image in say En, if I add a diffrent image for Spanish and come back and check English image, it shows the Spanish one. Similarly all language versions of the image field is showing the same last updated language image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the whole point of `Unversioned` media items. Unversioned means that there are no separate language versions. It's one shared.

If you set one in English, it will be same for any other language. If you change something in Spanish, it will be applied to all languages, including English.

If you want language specific media items, use `Versioned` template.

It's a bit confusing as when it comes to fields it's `Shared` checkbox which states whether field should have only single value shared for all languages, and `Unversioned` field checkbox has another meaning. Naming `Unversioned` for media items suggests something else. But still, this is how it works.

Comment: CMS isuue is fixed. But in the site, only En version images are showing even in other languages.

Comment: How are links to images rendered? Can you create another question showing the code used for generation of image links (or which SXA component you use), what it the url which is rendered, what are response cookies of image response (which site does it use and language)?

Comment: Okay. There is not much code written for it. Just fetching the image item from sitecore and showing it

Comment: You can read here about embedding language in media link: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/100/sitecore-experience-manager/build-item-and-media-urls.html

Comment: Thanks. So just changing the template to versioned, has fixed the issue it seems. But this image alone is highly caching that it just shows En image alone.